# Изменение цвета MenuItem при наведении в MenuButton

Tags: java, css, javafx

Пробую создать приложение на JavaFX. Для дизайна приложения использую SceneBuilder. Не получается задать цвет при наведении и размер MenuItem в MenuButton[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, задать цвет в style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Селектор `.menu-item:hover` работает только тогда, когда курсор находится над элементом. Если зажать кнопку мыши на пункте меню и сдвинуть курсор в сторону, то цвет вернется на исходный.

Поэтому лучше использовать селектор `.menu-item:focused` (обратите внимание, что название псевдокласса в JavaFx отличается от html варианта `:focus`).

Ширина выпадающего меню расчитывается как максимум значений `prefWidth` всех пунктов (плюс толщина рамки). 
Поэтому можно задать ее атрибутом `-fx-pref-width` в стиле класса пункта меню `.menu-item`.

Толщина рамки задается параметром `-fx-border-width` в стиле класса контейнера пунктов меню `.context-menu` и по-умолчанию равна 1.

Для указания точной ширины меню нужно вычесть толщину рамки 2 раза (слева и справа). Например, если нужна ширина меню 200, а толщина рамки 2, то указываем 196:

```
.menu-item:focused {
       -fx-background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212);
}

.menu-item {
       -fx-pref-width: 196;
       -fx-padding: 10;
}

.context-menu {
       -fx-border-color: rgb(0, 144, 163);
       -fx-padding: 0;
       -fx-border-width: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для изменения цвета элемента меню при наведении курсора мышки на него, можешь добавить в css, css класс для menuItem и добавить к нему псевдо-клас hover, выглядит это так:

```
.menuItem:hover {
       -fx-background-color: rgb(0, 125, 255);
}
```

Размер menuItem определяется его содержимым(текстом), и специальных методов для этого по моему нет.